How to replace a Passkey Owner for Safe Account
I followed the Safe Passkey Tutorial here: https://docs.safe.global/advanced/passkeys/tutorials/nuxt
I noticed that the owner of all passkey-based safe accounts is the safe-webauthn-shared-signer.sol.
I want to implement replacing the passkey with a new one for an existing account by using the swapOwner function of the safe account. But since the owner is the same for every passkey-based safe account this does not work.
I was wondering whether there is a way to archive removing/adding passkeys as owners for a safe account.
Thanks in advance :)

To afford gas the first passkey used is the SafeWebAuthnSharedSigner contract. To add additional passkeys you need to call the SafeWebAuthnSignerFactory contract and deploy a new SafeWebAuthnSignerProxy contract instance, that you can use as the owner of your Safe. You can deploy as many passkeys as you want using this factory.
Here there is more info on all the contracts involved: https://docs.safe.global/advanced/passkeys/passkeys-safe#passkey-contracts.
Find the address of the factory here: https://docs.safe.global/advanced/smart-account-supported-networks?module=Safe+Passkey+Module. Once you select a network: under "Modules" > "Safe Passkey Module" > "safe-webauthn-signer-factory.sol"
